# WPF Data binding: Changing items in the binded collection does not update binding source?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml

I have two classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> Details
    {
        get { return details; }
        set { details = value; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> Phones
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> phones;
            phones = new ObservableCollection<AccountDetail>();
            foreach (AccountDetail detail in Details)
            {
                if (detail.Type == DetailType.Phone)
                {
                    phones.Add(detail);
                }
            }
            return phones;
        }
        set
        {
            ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> phones;
            phones = value;
            foreach (AccountDetail detail in Details)
            {
                if (detail.Type == DetailType.Phone)
                {
                    Details.Remove(detail);
                }
            }
            foreach (AccountDetail detail in phones)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(detail.Value))
                {
                    Details.Add(detail); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> details;
}
```

and

```
public class AccountDetail
{
    public DetailType Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set { type = value; }
    }
    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }

    private DetailType type;
    private string value;
}
```

In my XAML file I have a `ListBox` named PhonesListBox which is data bound to the phones list (a property of the `Person` object):

```
<Window.Resources>

    <!-- Window controller -->
    <contollers:PersonWindowController 
        x:Key="WindowController" />

</Window.Resources>

...

<ListBox 
    Name="PhonesListBox" 
    Margin="0,25,0,0" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson.Phones, 
                  Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=WindowController}}"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />

...
```

In its code behind class, there's a handler for a button which adds a new item to that PhonesListBox:

```
private void AddPhoneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> phones;

    phones = (ObservableCollection<AccountDetail>)PhonesListBox.ItemsSource;
    phones.Add(new AccountDetail(DetailType.Phone));
}
```

The problem is, the newly added list box item is not added in the person's details observable collection, i.e. the Phones property is not updated (`set` is never called). Why? Where am I making a mistake?

Thanks for all the help.

#### UPDATE: I changed the AddPhoneButton_Click method to:

```
private void AddPhoneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PersonWindowController windowController;
    ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> details;

    windowController = (PersonWindowController)this.FindResource("WindowController");
    details = windowController.SelectedPerson.Details;
    details.Add(new AccountDetail(DetailType.Phone));
}
```

This updates the appropriate collection, which is `details` not `Phones` (as phones is just a *view or a getter* of a subset of detail items). Also, I realized I don't even need the Phones setter. The problem I am facing now is that my UI is not updated with the changes made to the details collection (and subsequently phones). I don't know how or where to call for the property changed as neither details nor phones are changing; their collection members are. Help. Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like you have an `ObservableCollection<AccountDetail>` with more than just phones in it, so it looks like you actually need a `CollectionViewSource` with a `Filter` added:

```
public class Person
{
    public ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> Details { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="phonesSource" 
        Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=WindowController}"
            Path="SelectedPerson.Details"  />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox 
        Name="PhonesListBox" 
        Margin="0,25,0,0" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource phonesSource}}"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CollectionViewSource source = 
        (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("phonesSource");
    source.Filter += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (((AccountDetail) e.Item).Type == DetailType.Phone)
                    e.Accepted = true;
            };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've updated my question above and I would massively appreciate if you could post your comment on it if possible. Thanks again.

Comment: your AddPhoneButton_Click method id OK, ive added a Path selection to my CollectionViewSource element that means it should now work.

Comment: Thanks for following me through. I just have one question regarding your approach with filters: I have four different list boxes in my WPF window, for phones, emails, addresses and others. Does this mean that I will need four different collection view sources and four different filters for each of them? Will that tackle the performance? Thanks again.

Comment: Having different CollectionViewSources (with optional filters) is the correct way to go from a performance and general approach point of view.

Comment: This is simply great and very easy to understand on my side. Thanks a million Dean. I've learned a lot today. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you create a new `ObservableCollection<AccountDetail>` each time the `Phones` property is retrieved? Typically the `Person` class would have a member field of type `ObservableCollection<AccountDetail>` that would just be returned in the getter for the `Phones` property, instead of creating a new one each time. You could populate this collection when an instance of `Person` is constructed, for example.

I don't know if this would fix your problem or not, but it seems like it should help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `Person` does have a `ObservableCollection<AccountDetail>` member and it is named `details` (and a corresponding property `Details`). The reason why I am returning a new collection is because I need only the details that represent the phone numbers in the `details` collection. If that is the cause of the issue, I don't know how to get around it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Changing you `Person` class to something like following should work :

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> Details
    {
        get { return details; }
        set { details = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> Phones
    {
        get
        {
            if (phones == null)
            {
                phones = new ObservableCollection<AccountDetail>();
            }

            phones.Clear();
            foreach (AccountDetail detail in Details)
            {
                if (detail.Type == DetailType.Phone)
                {
                    phones.Add(detail);
                }
            }
            return phones;
        }
        set
        {
            phones.Clear();

            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                phones.Add(item);
            }

            foreach (AccountDetail detail in Details)
            {
                if (detail.Type == DetailType.Phone)
                {
                    Details.Remove(detail);
                }
            }

            foreach (AccountDetail detail in phones)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(detail.Value))
                {
                    Details.Add(detail);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> details;
    public ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> phones;
}
```

The code is not tested and it may require a few changes from you to actually work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure that adding a new member field `phones` would help me, as the field `details` is actually containing all phones and other details (`Phones` is just a subset of `details` items). I've updated my question above and I would massively appreciate if you could post your comment on it if possible. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> Details
    {
        get { return details; }
        set { details = value; }
    }

    public void AddDetail(AccountDetail detail) {
        details.Add(detail);
        OnPropertyChanged("Phones");
    }

    public IEnumerable<AccountDetail> Phones
    {
        get
        {
            return details.Where(d => d.Type == DetailType.Phone);
        }
    }

    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> details;


    /// <summary>
    /// Called when a property changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the property.</param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a property value changes.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

}
```

You could call the AddDetail method from you button event handler:

```
private void AddPhoneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PersonWindowController windowController;
    ObservableCollection<AccountDetail> details;

    windowController = (PersonWindowController)this.FindResource("WindowController");
    windowController.SelectedPerson.AddDetail(new AccountDetail(DetailType.Phone));
}
```

Raising the OnPropertyChanged event for the Phones property will simply cause the WPF binding framework to requery the propery, and the Linq query to be re-evaluated, after you added a Phone detail to the list of Details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am puzzled where am I supposed to call the AddDetail method in my code. Also, I've updated my question above and I would massively appreciate if you could post your comment on it if possible. Thanks again.

Comment: You would call it from you button event handler (see my edited answer)